# Exporting MySQL to csv with specific row names

Tags: mysql

I haven't been able to find this anywhere, what I am trying to do is say export user_id, fname, lname.. How can I make the title of the cells in the csv User ID, First Name, Last Name?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through an [SQL Alias](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp):

```
SELECT col1 AS "User ID", col2 AS "First Name" FROM table;
```